# App loses Images when built

Tags: java, image, swing

For a project I am working on, I have made a Bingo Card. The basic functionality is that a Card is randomly generated and displayed in STD out as well as in a Swing GUI I made by hand. This application has multiple java files within.

BingoFinal.java - The main file. This is what's run when the program is run.
Bingo_Card.java - creates the Bingo card, prints it to STD out, and checks for bingo
BingoBG.java - Draws the background of the GUI with 2D graphics
DrawBingoCard.java - Calls BingoBG and also creates 25 labels with the board values. When Bingo_Card finds a matching number(inputted by STD IN), it no longer prints the number, and prints Chip.png(which is in the same package folder as the java files), a bingo chip image, making it look covered.

This works flawlessly when I run it through NetBeans, but when I clean and build it, then run the jar in terminal, everything works except for displaying the bingo chip image. Does anybody know why that would happen?

EDIT: Here is how I load the Image

```
ImageIcon chip; //declare ImageIcon
chip = new ImageIcon("chip75.png"); //define it as chip75.png. It is stored in package folder
JLabel B1Chip; //declare empty Label
B1Chip = new JLabel(chip); //define the Label with just the ImageIcon
B1Chip.setBounds(22, 112, chip.getIconWidth(), chip.getIconHeight()); //place at (22,112)
frame.add(B1Chip, null); //Add to frame
```

Comment: Show how you load the image.

Comment: Pease have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), regarding how to load images in the Project. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @Qwerky: Updated original question to show how it is loaded

Comment: @MichaelDornisch : Use `ClassNane.class.getResource("/chip75.png")` inside `ImageIcon` constructor :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw If you could, please post what you did as an answer. The link you included answered my question

Answer (score 3):

You should be accessing the `images`, by using :

```
ImageIcon chip = new ImageIcon(ClassName.class.getResource("/chip75.png"))
```

More information can be found on the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) of [tag: embedded-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded-resource) A detailed answer regarding adding `images` to the `NetBeans` Project is mentioned on the `info-page` link.

More importantly, it would be wise, that you use [ImageIO.read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.net.URL%29), since atleast it will let you know, if something goes wrong, by throwing `IOException`

```
Throws:

IllegalArgumentException - if input is null.
IOException - if an error occurs during reading.
```

`ImageIcon` on the other hand will hide the `exception` if any :-)

Answer (score 0):

copy the image files into jar or give absolute path of the image files